# Python requests, no attribute 'body'

Tags: python, rest, http, post, python-requests

I am trying to run a code similar to the one in this question: [How do I sign a POST request using HMAC-SHA512 and the Python requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100488/how-do-i-sign-a-post-request-using-hmac-sha512-and-the-python-requests-library)

I have the following code:

```
import requests
import hmac
import hashlib
from itertools import count
import time

headers = { 'nonce': '',
        'Key' : 'myKey',
        'Sign': '',}
payload = { 'command': 'returnCompleteBalances',
            'account': 'all'}
secret = 'mySecret'

NONCE_COUNTER = count(int(time.time() * 1000))
headers['nonce'] = next(NONCE_COUNTER)

request = requests.Request(
    'POST', 'https://poloniex.com/tradingApi',
    params=payload, headers=headers)
signature = hmac.new(secret, request.body, digestmod=hashlib.sha512)
request.headers['Sign'] = signature.hexdigest()

with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.send(request)
```

The following line :

```
signature = hmac.new(secret, request.body, digestmod=hashlib.sha512)
```

Throws this error: **'Request' object has no attribute 'body'**

Comment: Try: request.content

Comment: I get a similar error: 'Request' object has no attribute 'content'

Comment: Try request.text

Comment: Try to add a .prepare() in request object:
request = requests.Request(
    'POST', 'https://poloniex.com/tradingApi',
    params=payload, headers=headers).prepare()

Comment: request = requests.Request('POST', 'https://poloniex.com/tradingApi', params=payload, headers=headers).prepare()  this seemed to work while keeping requests.body

Comment: The result itself works, but unfortunately i am now getting 'error': 'Invalid Command' for a response

Comment: Why don't you just do a `json.dumps(payload)` and create a `sha512` of that and add it into the header fields and simply do a `request.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)`. This will make your life easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your source code has several problems:

1. For the POST method you can't use the argument `params`, but you need the argument `data`.
2. As mentioned before, you need the `.prepare()` method.
3. The parameter `nonce` needs to  be specified also in `payload`, not in `headers`.

This should work:

```
import requests
import hmac
import hashlib
from itertools import count
import time

NONCE_COUNTER = count(int(time.time() * 1000))

headers = { 'Key' : 'myKey',
            'Sign': '',}

payload = { 'nonce': next(NONCE_COUNTER),
            'command': 'returnCompleteBalances',
            'account': 'all'}

secret = 'mySecret'


request = requests.Request(
    'POST', 'https://poloniex.com/tradingApi',
    data=payload, headers=headers).prepare()
signature = hmac.new(secret, request.body, digestmod=hashlib.sha512)
request.headers['Sign'] = signature.hexdigest()


with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.send(request)
```