# How to do HMAC-SHA512 signing in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, sign, sha

I want to do a get request in the following format:

```
https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalance?apikey=API_KEY&currency=BTC
```

I do have the public and the secret key. However I found the following statement:

> For this version, we use a standard HMAC-SHA512 signing. Append apikey and nonce to your request and calculate the HMAC hash and include it under an apisign header

I don't really know how to properly encrypt my key. Using the plain secret key obviously returns "NONCE_NOT_PROVIDED". Everything I got is this:

```
current_price = requests.get("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalance?apikey=API_KEY&currency=BTC")
```

How to properly sign and encrypt the keys? Thank you.

Edit:

Current attempt looks like the following.

```
def getWalletSize():
    APIkey = b'29i52wp4'
    secret = b'10k84a9e'
    s = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalance?apikey=29i52wp4&currency=BTC"
    digest = hmac.new(secret, msg=s, digestmod=hashlib.sha512).digest()
    current_balance = requests.get(digest)
    return current_balance
```

However it raises the error `Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing`

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100488/how-do-i-sign-a-post-request-using-hmac-sha512-and-the-python-requests-library

Comment: The string must be in bytes, i.e. `s = b"...."`; however of course this doesn't get you anywhere. Look at the other

Answer (score 5):

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

API_KEY = 'public_key'
s = """GET https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalance?apikey=%s&currency=BTC""" % API_KEY

base64.b64encode(hmac.new("1234567890", msg=s, digestmod=hashlib.sha512).digest())
```

---

it signs the request

```
digest = hmac.new(secret_key, msg=thing_to_hash, digestmod=hashlib.sha512).digest()
```

and this encode it in base64

```
base64.b64encode(digest)
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Thanks. Please see my question. I edited it.