# How do I sign the body of a requests.Request in an Auth object's __call__ method?

Tags: python, python-requests, kraken.com

I'm trying to write a nice auth helper for kraken.  I want it to be as automatic as possible, so it needs to:

1. add a nonce (`time.time()*1000`) to the POST body
2. calculate a signature over the POST body
3. put the signature into the headers

I wrote the obvious code based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100488/how-do-i-sign-a-post-request-using-hmac-sha512-and-the-python-requests-library) answer:

```
class KrakenAuth(AuthBase):                                                                                                                                         
    """a requests-module-compatible auth module for kraken.com"""                                                                                                                  
    def __init__(self, key, secret):                                                                                                                                
        self.api_key    = key                                                                                                                                       
        self.secret_key = secret                                                                                                                                    

    def __call__(self, request):                                                                                                                                    
        #print("Auth got a %r" % type(request))                                                                                                                      
        nonce = int(1000*time.time())                                                                                                                               
        request.data = getattr(request, 'data', {})                                                                                                                 
        request.data['nonce'] = nonce                                                                                                                               
        request.prepare()                                                                                                                                           

        message = request.path_url + hashlib.sha256(str(nonce) + request.body).digest()                                                                             
        hmac_key = base64.b64decode(self.secret_key)                                                                                                                
        signature = hmac.new(hmac_key, message, hashlib.sha512).digest()                                                                                            
        signature = base64.b64encode(signature)                                                                                                                     

        request.headers.update({                                                                                                                                    
            'API-Key': self.api_key,                                                                                                                                
            'API-Sign': signature                                                                                                                                   
        })                                                                                                                                                          
        return request
```

and them I'm calling it (from a wrapper method on another object) like:

```
def _request(self, method, url, **kwargs):
    if not self._auth:
        self._auth = KrakenAuth(key, secret)
    if 'auth' not in kwargs:
        kwargs['auth'] = self._auth
    return self._session.request(method, URL + url, **kwargs)
```

...but it doesn't work.  The commented-out `print()` statement shows that it's getting a `PreparedRequest` object not a `Request` object, and thus the call to `request.prepare()` is a call to `PreparedRequest.prepare` does [nothing useful](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L307) because there's no `request.data` because it's already been converted into a `body` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access the `data` attribute of the request, because the authentication object is applied to a [`requests.PreparedRequest()` instance](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.PreparedRequest), which *has no `.data` attribute*.

The normal flow for a [`Session.request()` call](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Session.request) (used by all the `request.<method>` and `session.<method>` calls), is as follows:

- A `Request()` instance is created with all the same arguments as the original call
- The request is passed to [`Session.prepare_request()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Session.prepare_request), which merges in session-stored base values with the arguments of the original call first, then
- A [`PreparedRequest()` instance](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.PreparedRequest) is created
- The [`PreparedRequest.prepare()` method](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.PreparedRequest.prepare) is called on that prepared request instance, passing in the merged data from the `Request` instance and the session.
- The `prepare()` method calls the various `self.prepare_*` methods, including [`PreparedRequest.prepare_auth()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.PreparedRequest.prepare_auth).
- `PreparedRequest.prepare_auth()` calls `auth(self)` to give the authentication object a chance to attach information to the request.

Unfortunately for you, at no point during this flow will the original `data` mapping be available to anyone else but `PreparedRequest.prepare()` and `PreparedRequest.prepare_body()`, and in those methods the mapping is a local variable. You can't access it from the authentication object.

Your options are then:

- To *decode* the body again, and call `prepare_body()` with the updated mapping.
- To not use an authentication object, but use the other path from my answer; to explicitly create a prepared request and manipulate `data` first.
- To play merry hell with the Python stack and extract locals from the `prepare()` method that is two frames up. I really can't recommend this path.

To keep the authentication method encapsulated nicely, I'd go with decoding / re-encoding; the latter is simple enough by reusing [`PreparedRequest.prepare_body()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.PreparedRequest.prepare_body):

```
import base64
import hashlib
import hmac
import time
try:
    # Python 3
    from urllib.parse import parse_qs
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    from urlparse import parse_qs

from requests import AuthBase

URL_ENCODED = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'


class KrakenAuth(AuthBase):
    """a requests-module-compatible auth module for kraken.com"""
    def __init__(self, key, secret):
        self.api_key    = key
        self.secret_key = secret

    def __call__(self, request):
        ctheader = request.headers.get('Content-Type')
        assert (
            request.method == 'POST' and (
                ctheader == URL_ENCODED or
                requests.headers.get('Content-Length') == '0'
            )
        ), "Must be a POST request using form data, or empty"

        # insert the nonce in the encoded body
        data = parse_qs(request.body)
        data['nonce'] = nonce
        request.prepare_body(data, None, None)

        body = request.body
        if not isinstance(body, bytes):   # Python 3
            body = body.encode('latin1')  # standard encoding for HTTP

        message = request.path_url + hashlib.sha256(b'%s%s' % (nonce, body)).digest()
        hmac_key = base64.b64decode(self.secret_key)
        signature = hmac.new(hmac_key, message, hashlib.sha512).digest()
        signature = base64.b64encode(signature)

        request.headers.update({
            'API-Key': self.api_key,
            'API-Sign': signature
        })
        return request
```